# Read 3rd party config section

Tags: c#, configuration

In a web.config file, I have a 3rd party settings section :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="TheProduct">
      <section name="TheSection" type="TheCompany.TheProduct.TheSectionConfigurationHandler, TheCompany.TheProduct, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1e9bee111e9429c" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <TheProduct>
     <TheSection somevalue="true" />
  </TheProduct>
</configuration>
```

I want to read the value of this section **from another application**, but when I try to find the section, I always get `null`.

Here is my code :

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
    @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TheProduct\web.config"
    );
var settings = config.GetSection("TheProduct/TheSection"); // always null
```

What is the correct way to retrieve the config section ?

**[Edit]** If the calling app, which defines the same section, I can do :

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TheProduct/TheSection");
```

and it's working. Mybe I'm not opening the web.config file using the correct way ?

Comment: Do you have a reference to `TheCompany.TheProduct, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1e9bee111e9429c` in your application?

Comment: No... actually the section handler is internal in the 3rd party library. I wanted to use reflection to read the value.

Comment: Edit: I have the reference to the 3rd party lib... I just can't instantiate the type myself

Comment: May it will help, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826744/how-to-share-configuration-file-for-web-and-window-application>

Answer (score 0):

Using the configuration manager requires that your application be able to instantiate the actual strongly-typed configuration objects. If you can't add a reference to the defining assembly, then your only choice is to use one of the XML api's (either `System.Xml` or `System.Linq.Xml`) to read it manually, in which case you won't be using the configuration manager at all.

Comment: I can't get the section of the remote app, but I can get the section of the current app. I think it's not a problem of extracting the value, but reading the section