# Local settings for WCF

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, web-config

Is it possible to have common `web.config` file for WCF project and different file on each developer's machine, which will override some of the attribute?

For example it will change the

```
     <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
```

to

```
      <security mode="None"/>
```

Comment: It will help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826744/share-config-file-for-web-and-window-app-best-way/9872189#9872189].

Comment: Hi Orim, i have added the same link as an answer to complete the thread, please accept and vote it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the following Link, it will help you to achieve the same.

[Share Config file for Web and Window App (Best Way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826744/share-config-file-for-web-and-window-app-best-way/9872189#9872189%5D)